# How to rollback a removed entity to its previous state?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

Consider the following situation:

```
public class EntityA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityA EntityA { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("EF_SPIKE")
    {
    }

    public IDbSet<EntityA> EntityAs { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<EntityB> EntityBs { get; set; } 
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        var a = context.EntityAs.Create();
        context.EntityAs.Add(a);

        var b = context.EntityBs.Create();
        b.EntityA = a;
        context.EntityBs.Add(b);

        context.SaveChanges();

        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            context.EntityBs.Remove(b);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        Trace.Assert(b.EntityA == null);
        Trace.Assert(context.EntityBs.Local.All(x => x.Id != b.Id));
        Trace.Assert(context.EntityBs.Any(x => x.Id == b.Id));
    }
}
```

So although the transaction is rolled back and the entity still exists in the database, the entity framework entity `b` no longer exists in the local cache, loses all of its foreign key references and `b` can no longer be worked with.

This behaviour seems odd to me since although I've rolled back, my entity is still dead.

Is there any standard workaround to this so that:

```
Trace.Assert(context.EntityBs.Local.Any(x => x.Id == b.Id));
```

passes?

Comment: I don't think there is other than storing its Id after the first `SaveChanges()` and re-fetching it after the roll back. I assume that in real life you would roll back conditionally and still want to us an entity afterwards?

Comment: You still have the Id as that remains in the entity. Yes after the roll back occurs then I still want to use the entity. I'm just repopulating it on the transaction completed event at the moment - just wondered if there was a better way.